# JavaFx response to SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, swing, javafx, event-dispatch-thread, mixing

So I am aware that JavaFx's method of updating the GUI while using a thread is called Task but does the code work in similar way or are there any differences. let me give you a swing example:

**Another class outside the GUI that runs as a thread**

```
public void run(){
    while (socket.isConnected()) {
        String x = input.next();
        System.out.println(x);
        mg.updateChat(x)
    }
}
```

**Inside the actual GUI**

```
public void updateChat(final String input){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtChat.setText(input); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Does Task work the exact same way? Or are there differences and if there are how would you modify this code to work in a JavaFx project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you looking for SwingUtil.invokeLater counterparts in JavaFX. If yes, it is:

```
Platform.runLater(java.lang.Runnable runnable)
```

Comment: As far as I can understand [the api]( http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html), yes. I use it to update javafx ui controls in multithreaded environment just like I use SwingUtilities.invokeLater for Swing controls.

Comment: No luck here, my UI freezes when I'm doing runLater.

Comment: Make sure your long running task is running inside a Task and that whenever you need to update the ui you call Platform.runLater.  Do not run long running tasks inside runLater because your UI will then freeze.

Comment: The lambda version is nice Platform.runLater(() -> txtChat.setText(input))