# JavaFX: Updating UI elements in a Controller class from a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

In JavaFX, I have a Controller class that pulls control components from an FXML file and has methods that act on the component, shown with a Label here:

```
public class ViewController {
    @FXML private Label labelStatus;

    public void updateStatusLabel(String label) {
        labelStatus.setText("Status: " + label);
    }    
}
```

I also have a Java Thread with a run() method, like this:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        super.run();    
    }
}
```

This Server thread handles some socket connections that I need for my particular application. After a connection has been established (in the run() method -- not shown), I need to update the Label in the FXML Controller. How would I do this?

Note: I've purposely made my code and question general so it may help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

You call [Platform.runLater(runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) off the JavaFX UI thread to execute a runnable that updates elements of the active JavaFX Scene Graph on the JavaFX UI thread.

Also review [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm), with the [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) classes and see if that is not a more appropriate solution to your particular task.

For more information, see:

- [Usage of JavaFX Platform.runLater and access to UI from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160410/usage-of-javafx-platform-runlater-and-access-to-ui-from-a-different-thread).
- [Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx)
- [JavaFx response to SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984310/javafx-response-to-swingutilities-invokelater)