# How to run two methods in sequence with the same button in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, metadata

I'm trying to fill a `listview` with the artist and title of songs using the `open()` method.
To achieve this I created the `artist` and `title` `ArrayLists` and merged them using the `create()` method.

The problem is, when I try to run `create()` inside `open()` nothing happens. However, if I assign the `create()` method to a different button and click it after using the `filechooser` everything works fine.

So, I would like to know if it is possible to run the `create()` method after the `open()` method using only one button via fxml or regular java code.

```
public class PLController implements Initializable {

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {        
    list.setItems(visibleList);
}

List<File> filelist = new ArrayList<File>();
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> artist = new ArrayList<String>();
ObservableList<String> visibleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
ListView<String> list;
@FXML
Button impButton;

public void create(){
    for(int i = 0; i < title.size(); i++){
    visibleList.add(artist.get(i) +" - " +title.get(i));
    Collections.sort(visibleList);
    }
}

public void handleMetadata(String key, Object value){
    if (key.equals("title")){
        title.add(value.toString());
    }
    if (key.equals("artist")){
        artist.add(value.toString());
    }
}

public void open(){
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    filelist = chooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(impButton.getScene().getWindow());
    for(File f:filelist){
    try {
        Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
        media.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, Object>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> change) {
                if(change.wasAdded()) {
                    handleMetadata(change.getKey(), change.getValueAdded());
                }
            }
        }); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }create(); //Nothing happens
}
```

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? What do you expect to happen? Why are you sorting the list on all iterations of the loop? Are you aware of [`Platform.runLater`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984310/javafx-response-to-swingutilities-invokelater)?

Comment: It means literally nothing happens, I expect the `listview` to be filled with the values in `visibleList`. 
I was not aware of `Platform.runLater`, will check it out.

Comment: Make sure the list is not empty. If it is not, you should **always** update the GUI in the UI thread (in case of JavaFX through `Platform.runLater`).

Comment: Where is `visibleList` associated with the `ListView`?

Comment: @m0skit0 apparently the list is empty while the `open()` method doesn't end, therefore I cannot call `create()` inside it.

@James_D at `list.setItems(visibleList);`4th line

Comment: Peralta: Thanks - sorry I missed that somehow... @m0skit0 The listener on the metadata will be invoked on the FX Application Thread anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the `Media` object does not have its metadata initialized immediately. (It needs to read data from the URL and populate those metadata as it receives them.) That is why the metadata are exposed as an `ObservableMap`. When you reach the end of your `open()` method, it is highly unlikely that the metadata will have been initialized, so your `create()` method will not see any data at that point.

What you need to do is observe the map, and update the `ListView` once both the artist and title are available. The best way to do this, in my opinion, is to encapsulate the information you want into a separate class:

```
public class Video {
    private final Media media ;
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper artist = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("Unknown");
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper title = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("Title");

    public Video(File file) {
        try {
            this.media = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());

            artist.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                Object a = media.getMetadata().get("artist");
                return a == null ? "Unknown" : a.toString();
            }, media.getMetadata()));

            title.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                Object t = media.getMetadata().get("title");
                return t == null ? "Unknown" : t.toString();
            }, media.getMetadata()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create Video for "+file, e);
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty titleProperty() {
        return title.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty artistProperty() {
        return artist.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public final String getArtist() {
        return artist.get();
    }

    public final Media getMedia() {
        return media ;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `ListView<Video>` to display the videos. Use a cell factory to display the artist and the title in the format you want. You can make sure that the observable list fires updates when either the `artist` or `title` properties change, and you can keep it sorted via a `SortedList`.

```
@FXML
private ListView<Video> list ;

private ObservableList<Video> visibleList ;

public void initialize() {
    visibleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        // make list fire updates when artist or title change:
        v -> new Observable[] {v.artistProperty(), v.titleProperty()});

    list.setItems(new SortedList<>(list, Comparator.comparing(this::formatVideo)));

    list.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Video>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Video item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
            setText(formatVideo(item));
        }
    });
}

@FXML
private void open() {
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    List<File> fileList = chooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(impButton.getScene().getWindow());
    if (fileList != null) {
        fileList.stream()
        .map(Video::new)
        .forEach(visibleList::add);
    }
}

private String formatVideo(Video v) {
    if (v == null) return "" ;
    return String.format("%s - %s", v.getArtist(), v.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, lots of concepts here I don't understand though, I'll study a bit and try to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Simply creating a Media object and assigning a listener to it won't fire the code in the listener. So the title list in your code remains empty. The create() method is called, but since you are iterating over an empty list, nothing actually happens.

Use a debugger or add some logging information in such cases.

Also, you should sort the list after the for loop, not every time you add an item.

Comment: But why does it work if I call `create()` with a separate button?

Comment: Because of a race condition. Eventually the change listener fires. After that your title list is filled. And after that you click the button manually. Just output some logging and you'll see.

Comment: So how do I make the `create()` method wait for the listener to fire? Just add `.wait(x amount of time)`?

Comment: Invoke the logic to update `visibleList` from inside the handler on the metadata. You need to be a little careful, as that handler will be invoked each time the map changes.