# JavaFXPorts with Clojure: "This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main"

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, clojure, javafxports

I have my main namespace inserted below; when I run `./gradlew run`, it will run fine *only if* I comment out the `primary-screen (.getPrimary Screen)` line, so this seems to be broken for whatever reason?

```
(ns lyrion.cec
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojurefx.clojurefx :as fx])
  (:import (javafx.stage Stage Screen)
           (javafx.scene Scene)
           (javafx.scene.control Label)
           (javafx.geometry Rectangle2D)))

(defn init []
  nil)

(defn start [^Stage stage]
  (let [content ^Label (Label. "Hello World")
        primary-screen (.getPrimary Screen)
        ;;visual-bounds ^Rectangle2D (.getVisualBounds ^Screen primary-screen)
        ;;scene ^Scene (Scene. content (.getWidth visual-bounds) (.getHeight visual-bounds))
        scene ^Scene (Scene. content 800 600)]
    (.setScene stage scene)
    (.show stage)))

(defn stop []
  nil)

(defn -main
  ""
  [& args]
  (fx/start-app init start stop))
```

`fx/start-app` is a function of my clojurefx library that creates an `Application` subclass and calls init, start and stop accordingly as per specification. I never had a problem with that so far in any desktop JavaFX application. It is also weird that apparently, doing this myself is necessary in JavaFXPorts even though all examples suggest otherwise.

Comment: Not sure about your specific problem, but you may be interested in this version:  https://github.com/fn-fx/fn-fx

Comment: Also this question may have relevance:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984310/javafx-response-to-swingutilities-invokelater

Comment: `runLater` doesn't help. It's not even necessary at that point, since `start` gets called on the event thread to begin with (otherwise, neiter `setScene` nor `show` would work).